# Java String RegularExpressions

Tags: java, regex

Team,
I had a task. i.e., i want to check `98%` in a blcvk of data.
I trying to write some regex but its giving continuous error.

```
String str="OAM-2 OMFUL abmasc01 and prdrot01 98% users NB in host nus918pe locked.";
if(str.matches("[0-9][0-9]%"))
```

but it is returning false.

Response is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pattern/matcher/find method. `matches` applies the regex to the whole string.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{2}%");
String test = "OAM-2 OMFUL abmasc01 and prdrot01 98% users NB in host nus918pe locked.";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Matched!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
str.matches(".*[0-9][0-9]%.*")
```

or (`\d` = digit):

```
str.matches(".*\\d\\d%.*")
```

The matching pattern should also match the characters that come before/after the `98%` which is why you should add the `.*`

*Comment:*
You can use Pattern matcher like the others suggested, it's especially effective if you want to extract `98%` out of the string - but if you're just looking to find if there's a match - I find `.matches()` to be simpler to use.

Comment: @user1835935 Welcome to Stackoverflow! if the answers were helpful you should pick up one of them and "accept" it by clicking on the V (check sign) to the top left of the question. You should do the same with the other questions you've posted. In case you find more than one answer helpful (you can accept only one) you can upvote the other helpful answers by clicking the "up arrow".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex `\d{1,2}(\.\d{0,2})?%` this will match `98%` or percentage with decimal values like `98.56%`as well.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,2}(\\.\\d{0,2})?%");
String yourString= "OAM-2 OMFUL abmasc01 and prdrot01 98% users NB in host nus918pe locked.";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourString);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.matches("[0-9][0-9]%")` actually applies this regex `^[0-9][0-9]%$`, which is anchored at start and end. Others have described solutions to this already.